# Can a reducer writes into two different files?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

In map-reduce, emitting in reducer results in writing to an output file with a name like "output-00000". What if I want to output into two different files (with 2 different names apparently) within a reducer? If it is possible how I can change the name of the output files from default?

Comment: https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/output/MultipleOutputs.html

Answer (score 4):

Use [MultipleTextOutputFormat](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/lib/MultipleTextOutputFormat.html). `MultipleOutputFormat` allows to write the output data to different output files. Two variants of MultipleOutputFormat are `MultipleSequenceFileOutputFormat` and `MultipleTextOutputFormat`.

Simple example is shown [here.](https://sites.google.com/site/hadoopandhive/home/how-to-write-output-to-multiple-named-files-in-hadoop-using-multipletextoutputformat)